# Angular 6 sharing data between components using Service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

In my home component which is a children of Dashboard component, the object connectedUser injected in layoutService is undefined in home component (home userID & home connectedUser in home component logs);
something is missing here ?

home.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HomeRoutingModule } from './home-routing.module';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
/**
 *
 *
 *
 * @export
 * @class AccueilModule
 */

@NgModule({
    imports: [
          CommonModule,
          ReactiveFormsModule,
          HomeRoutingModule,
          FormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        HomeComponent
        ],
    providers: [

    ]
  })
  export class HomeModule {}
```

dashboard.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserConnected } from 'src/app/models/userConnected';
import { LayoutService } from '../services/layout.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  currentDate: String;
  userSaml = new UserConnected();
  constructor(public layoutService: LayoutService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    /* show today's date */
    var today = new Date();
    this.currentDate = today.getDate() + '/' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + today.getFullYear();
    /* show today's date */

    this.layoutService.getConnectedUser().subscribe(

      (data) => {
        this.userSaml = data;
        this.layoutService.connectedUser.matricule = this.userSaml.matricule;
        this.layoutService.connectedUser.profil = this.userSaml.profil;
        this.layoutService.connectedUser.uid = this.userSaml.uid;
        this.layoutService.connectedUser.username = this.userSaml.username;
        this.layoutService.connectedUser.city = this.userSaml.city;
      },
      (err) => {
        throw err;
      }
    );

  }

}
```

app-routine.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './shared/layout/dashboard/dashboard.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent
    , children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule'
      },
      {

        path: 'rapport',
        loadChildren: '../rapport/rapport.module#RapportModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'admin',
        loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule'
      }
    ]
  }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LayoutService } from '../shared/layout/services/layout.service';
import { UserConnected } from '../models/userConnected';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public layoutService: LayoutService) { }
  userID: string;
  userExists : boolean = false;
  connectedUser = new UserConnected;
  ngOnInit() : void {
    this.connectedUser = this.layoutService.connectedUser;
    console.log("home connectedUser" + JSON.stringify(this.connectedUser));
    this.userID = this.connectedUser.uid;
    console.log("home userID" + this.userID);

    this.adminService.verifyUser(this.userID)
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.userExists = true;
        },
        (err) => {
          this.userExists = false;
        }
      );
  }

}
```

and finally, this is my layoutService

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../../../environments/environment';
import { UserConnected } from 'src/app/models/userConnected';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LayoutService {
  
  connectedUser : UserConnected;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

   getConnectedUser(){
    return this.http.get<UserConnected>(environment.RAA_ROOT + '/connectedUser');
  }

}
```

Comment: at this point what would be interesting to know is what is inside your layoutService, could you share code please?

Comment: Hello, I have edited my post by adding the layoutService code. thanks

Comment: Are you sure there is no exception inside the `HomeComponent` in this line: `this.layoutService.connectedUser.matricule = this.userSaml.matricule;`. It looks like you are trying to set a property value of undefined. I cannot see where you are initializing the `connectedUser` property in your service.

Comment: Hi, no exception cause the userSaml object is correctly filled by data, but I agree that I need to initialize connectedUser in my service, but doing this doesn't solve this issue, that's why I tought that the initialization make the value undefined that's why I have kept initialization inside home component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, change the line in your HomeComponent from:

`this.connectedUser = this.layoutService.connectedUser;`

into:

`this.connectedUser = this.layoutService.getConnectedUser()`

Since you have not assigned it in your **layoutService**, **layoutService.connectedUser** will return undefined.
Be aware, that **http.get** is asynchronous so it returns an observable, which you need to subscribe to in order to use it in your component(or use asyncPipe if you want to use it in your template).

Going further:

`this.layoutService.getConnectedUser().subscribe((connectedUser) => { this.connectedUser = connectedUser; })`

More explanation here:
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6

Comment: Awesome explanation, thank you so much !!

Answer (score 2):

*connectedUser* of **`LayoutService`** is causing the problem in your case

```
connectedUser : UserConnected = new UserConnected();
```

This will give you the object type of ***UserConnected*** class, so you won't get that error while access it. Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: I did that before but only connectedUser = new UserConnected(); and it doesn't work. what is the difference?

Comment: The  ` : UserConnected` part just tells the type of your property.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to change the service implementation and introduce a better caching:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../../../environments/environment';
import { UserConnected } from 'src/app/models/userConnected';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LayoutService {
  
  private _cachedConnectedUser: UserConnected;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

   getConnectedUser(): Observable<UserConnected> {

    if (this._cachedConnectedUser ) {
      return of(this._cachedConnectedUser);
    }

    return this.http.get<UserConnected>(environment.RAA_ROOT + '/connectedUser')
     .map(response =>  {
       this._cachedConnectedUser = response.body;
       return this._cachedConnectedUser;
     });
  }    
}
```

Now you are able to call always `layoutService.getConnectedUser()` to recieve the object.
You do not have to handle all those local variables.

You could improve even this caching mechanism like explained [here](https://blog.fullstacktraining.com/caching-http-requests-with-angular/)

Comment: Very well explained, I admit that I have never had the opportunity to use this approach, interesting :) thank you so much